# JSF: Partially adding text to component from AJAX call

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want a inputTextarea to display lines appended to some text file. I imagine it like this: The user clicks a commandButton that does a AJAX call.

My problem is: The text will only be rendered when the action returns. However, my action should look like this:

```
while(true) {
  String newData = getSomeMoreDataFromServer();
  // append the new data to a textarea and the user should see it immediately
  if(blabla) { break; } 
}
```

Is this even possible? The part that's commented out is the part that bothers me.

Can the user even set the break condition in the form somehow?

I'm using JSF 2 (MyFaces) + Tomahawk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible from inside the backing bean action method. Also having a `while(true)` is very CPU-inefficient, you'd rather like to avoid that in a multi-user environment. What you're looking for is ajax poll/push. This is not provided in the standard JSF implementation and also not in Tomahawk. [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) for example, supports ajax poll/push components [`<p:poll>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) and [`<p:push>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chat.jsf).

Comment: Thank you! I will check out PrimeFaces.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that blueish `<p:poll>` and `<p:push>` in my answer are actually links.